# Xattribute in a loop in c#

Tags: c#, loops, xattribute

```
public override XElement createXmlElement()
{
    XElement XShape = new XElement("Shape", new XAttribute("Name", "freeline"),
        new XElement("Pen_Details",
        new XAttribute("PenColor", this.PenColor.ToArgb().ToString("X")),
        new XAttribute("PenWidth", this.PenWidth),
        (for(int i = 0; i < FreeList.Count; i++)
        {
            new XElement("Point", new XAttribute("X", this.Pt1.X), new XAttribute("Y", this.Pt1.Y));
        }));

    return XShape;
}
```

I need to add the points in a loop. How can I do that?

The output below code:

```
<Shapes> 
    <Shape Name="freeline"> 
        <Pen_Details PenWidth="2" PenColor="FFFF0000"> 
            <Point> X='127' Y='71'</Point> 
            <Point> X='128' Y='71'</Point> 
            <Point> X='130' Y='71'</Point>
        </Pen_Details>
    </Shape>
</Shapes>
```

Comment: what do you mean by your question?  It seems that the points are added to the document in a loop.  What should the output look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). Use this:

```
FreeList.Select(p => new XElement("Point",
                          new XAttribute("X", p.X),
                          new XAttribute("Y", p.Y))).ToArray();
```

Instead of this:

```
(for(int i = 0; i < FreeList.Count; i++)
{
    new XElement("Point",
                 new XAttribute("X", this.Pt1.X),
                 new XAttribute("Y", this.Pt1.Y));
}));
```

And your method is going to be much more shorter:

```
public override XElement createXmlElement()
{
    return new XElement("Shape",
        new XAttribute("Name", "freeline"),
        new XElement("Pen_Details",
            new XAttribute("PenColor", this.PenColor.ToArgb().ToString("X")),
            new XAttribute("PenWidth", this.PenWidth),
            FreeList.Select(p => new XElement("Point",
                                  new XAttribute("X", p.X),
                                  new XAttribute("Y", p.Y))).ToArray()));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Having made a few assumptions, I think that this reworked version of your `createXmlElement` method should do what you want. It breaks down the creation of the `XElement` into multiple, discrete, steps. This should make it easier to follow and understand.

```
public static XElement CreateXmlElement()
{
    var penDetails = new XElement("Pen_Details");
    penDetails.Add(new XAttribute("PenColor", PenColor.ToArgb().ToString("X")));
    penDetails.Add(new XAttribute("PenWidth", PenWidth));

    for (int i = 0; i < FreeList.Count; i++)
    {
        penDetails.Add(new XElement("Point", new XAttribute("X", FreeList[i].X), new XAttribute("Y", FreeList[i].Y)));
    };

    var shape = new XElement("Shape", new XAttribute("Name", "freeline"));
    shape.Add(penDetails);

    var shapes = new XElement("Shapes");
    shapes.Add(shape);

    return shapes;
}
```

Note that the `Point` elements will look like this...

```
<Point X='127' Y='71'></Point>
```

Rather than...

```
<Point> X='127' Y='71'</Point>
```